# Repeated patients in a matched case control study - how to cluster the standard errors

Tags: r, matching, clustered-standard-errors

I'm doing a matched case control study to assess the impact of a disease on healthcare usage. I'm using observational data, and I have a panel of patients with many years observations each. In the case of patients with the disease, I have a simple cross-section - I track them from the point of first diagnosis, so they only appear once in the dataset. However, controls appear across multiple years.

I've performed exact matching, for the sake of simplicity let's say I've used sex, age and calendar year (there are a few more covariates in practice). The match worked well, achieving good balance and retaining the vast majority of my "treatment" group.

However, single individual control patients are assigned to different subclasses across different years. My dilemma is how to account for the non-independence of these observations when estimating the difference between treatment and control groups on various metrics of healthcare usage.

The advice in the [MatchIt documentation](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/articles/estimating-effects.html) is:

> The only change that needs to be made to the Standard Case is that one should change `vcov = ~subclass` to `vcov = "HC3"` in the calls to comparisons() and predictions() to use robust SEs instead of cluster-robust SEs.

In my case, I think I need to cluster the standard errors at the patient level, so I have tried `vcov = ~patient_id` and `vcov = ~subclass + patient_id` with the latter producing the widest confidence intervals (although very little difference in practice across all these specifications).

Am I barking up the wrong tree, or should I indeed be clustering standard errors at the patient level? And is this the way to do it using `MatchIt`?

Comment: Did you try using the `unit.id` argument to `matchit()`, which prevents observations from the same unit from being used more than once? That way you won't have repeated use of the control units and can use standard procedures. Otherwise what you're doing is a form of matching with replacement that is not well understood.

Comment: Ah no, I wasn't aware of the `unit.id` argument - thanks @Noah I will give that a try. (Although it would be to fun to be theoretically pioneering, that was not my intention ;-))

Comment: Reading your docs more carefully, it sounds like the other way to go would be to switch to nearest neighbour matching - then the way I've tried to cluster the SEs would be in line with the approach you describe by Austin and Cafri. Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: I have now tried using the `unit.id` argument, supplying the variable name alone, the variable name as a string, and the column directly in `df$colname` format, but it's producing the same matched sample, with duplicate patients, as when I don't set the argument. What am I doing wrong? (I've found your explanation in the docs but I can't find a vignette that uses it)

Comment: Hm, are you using the updated version of `MatchIt`? And are you using it with `method = "nearest"`? If so, it sounds like a bug and I'll need to investigate.

Comment: I just installed it, so think it's to up-to-date but I'll check. But no, I'm doing exact matching so `method = "exact"`. Can you use the `unit.id` argument when performing exact matching?

Comment: Version 4.4.0 - hopefully close enough

Comment: Ah, well that's your problem. You need to use `method = "nearest"`. `method = "exact"` is a stratification method; it doesn't create pairs. If you want pairs, you need to use `method = "nearest"`. You can supply the covariate you want to exactly match on to the `exact` argument.

Comment: OK thanks, that has worked. One question: `matchit` was able to enforce no replacement, even across the strata I specified using `exact`... Given that, is there a way to tweak the function so it can do exact matching without replacement?

Comment: Oh, and for the benefit of anyone who stumbles across this exchange, the way to supply `unit.id` with your variable is `~ varname` format. It would be great to add that to the docs when you get a chance @Noah

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your comment, is there a typo in it? You said `matchit` can do exact matching without replacement, so what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Sorry I haven't checked this thread for a while. What I mean is, rather than having to do it in a hacky way by specifying nearest neighbour matching, then specifying all the same variables again for exact matching, and ending up with pairs (which in my case meant discarding a lot of controls) just allow true exact matching, dividing the observations into strata, but only allow each `unit.id` to be used once

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work because a single unit ID might be split between strata, in which case how would you decide which instance of that unit should be retained and which should be discarded? The method isn't hacky, it's the right way to use it and what you are requesting is quite unusual and specific. You don't need to specify the same variable in the main formula and the `exact` argument; just including them in the `exact` argument is enough (e.g., `matchit(treat ~ 1, exact = ~age + sex)`). If you want the option to retain many matches, set a high `ratio`.

Comment: Ah that's a good idea, but I'm guessing if I set a ratio of say, 3, any treatment units with less than 3 matches will drop out? I'm just trying to think of a method that retains as many control units as possible. On how to allocate them, I guess however you're doing it already for nearest neighbour matching - is it just "first come first served" as you work your way down the treatment units? Could you do the same thing looping through the strata? Anyway, it was just an idea to add some more functionality to your package with what seemed to me a minor tweak - no worries if it's harder than that

Comment: Nope, if a unit doesn't get 3 matches, it gets all the matches it can, so control units are still retained. If you want to retain many control units, just set a high matching ratio. It is first-come-first-served, but the user specifies the order in which that is done. There is no principled way to order exact matching strata. But I don't think that functionality is necessary because it's already available with `method = "nearest"`.

Comment: No you're right, that's great - I can get exactly the behaviour I want by just setting `ratio = Inf` - thanks!